# What comes in between prepend() and append()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, prepend

I'll make to quick. I'm trying to position an element wrt my target. Normally we have prepend (before the target) and append (after the target). But is there smth along those lines that helps us place that element ON what we’re targeting, instead of putting it before (prepend) or after(append)?

Comment: ***On*** what are you targeting? If it contains a child element you can replace or position that element's ```innerHTML```, or append/prepend it to that child element.

Comment: Let's say there's a target called 'X'. And I'm trying to position some element 'B' on the page. I can either use prepend and put B before X or I can use append and put B after X. How can I put B ON X?

Comment: If you want to overlay B on X, then you need to insert it inside of X and position it absolutely with an inset of 0.

Comment: Would that be [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith)?

Comment: DOM only knows before and after since there can't be more than one element at the same position in the DOM. CSS knows absolute positioning. But your question doesn't make clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want new HTML Elements add to target... I don't know if this is what you want.

```js
$('.target-x').html('<div class="target-b">new elements</div>')
```

```css
.target-x {background:#bbb;padding:10px;}
.target-b {background:#fff;color:#222;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="target-top">Elements</div>
    <div class="target-x">New Elements Target</div>
    <div class="target-bottom">Elements</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute` on a `:before` to place it ON the actual content.

HTML

```
<div class="example">This is an example div</div>
```

CSS

```
.example {
  background-color: #5BC8F7;
}

.example::before {
  position:absolute;
  content: "Above!";
  background-color: #FFBA10;
}
```